# Swift iOS. How can I get indexPath's of cells in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, nsindexpath

I need to update collectionView when without `reloadData()` (To animatedly insert and delete cells) So I want to get array of indexPaths of cells.

Comment: The question is not clear enough. Are you trying to get index paths of visible cells?

Comment: @StefanSalatic no, Im trying to get indexpathes of all cells of my CollectionView. Is it possible ? Because collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems() works only when collectionView have a small amount of cells

Comment: I have updated the answer on how to get all NSIndexPaths. This should work for you now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the array of index paths for currently visible UICollectionView cells just call

```
collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems()
```

To get all cells you can create your own array using the data source methods.

```
var indexPaths: [NSIndexPath] = []
for s in 0..<collectionView.numberOfSections() {
    for i in 0..<collectionView.numberOfItemsInSection(s) {
        indexPaths.append(NSIndexPath(forItem: i, inSection: s))
    }
}
```

Comment: very very thank You )